# Navigation menu - making the background color fill the whole page rather than the viewport

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am having a problem with the design of the left navigation bar. Specifically, I want the grey color of the bar to appear vertically throughout the whole page.

Right now, the gray bar is just stopped at the end of the viewport. Is there a way to extend the bar to infinity?

Here is the CSS snippet of the vertical nav bar:

```
#navbar{
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: #5e5e5e;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/twkgR/264/

Comment: can you be more specific? your fiddle doesn't stop anywhere - it goes the entire height.

Comment: Josh Crozier below got it. Add position: relative to the body. http://jsfiddle.net/cajrk7qr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you could relatively position the `body` element. In doing so, the `#menu` is absolutely positioned relative to the `body`. Prior to this, the `#menu` element was absolutely positioned relative to the window, which is why it ended at the viewport.

Check the [**updated example**](http://jsfiddle.net/x3y623dg/).

```
body {
    position: relative;
}
#menu {
    position: absolute;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: s***, sorry, I got the wrong fiddle link. It worked well with that fiddle, but not with mine :(

Comment: @vagaryblue It works in that example you just posted - http://jsfiddle.net/x3y623dg/

Comment: that was a relief from a headache! My original html code has this line <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> -->, and it screwed up the position: relative attribute of the body.

Comment: Also, is it ok to use percentage in css nowadays? I tested with height: 100vh but it didn't work as desired.

Comment: @vagaryblue `100vh` wouldn't have worked because those are **viewport** relative units (i.e., 100% of the viewport, not the document). But yea, percentages are fully supported by all browsers.